# Listing the IP's an app is communicating with

Tags: java, android, network-programming

I am looking to list the IP's that any given android app is communicating programmatically.  I really cannot find anything on how to do this.  I've looked through then following libraries:

- android.net
- java.net
- most of the java.security/android.security

None of them seem to hold what I am looking to do.  If anyone has any input, that would be really awesome.

Also, to extend this, it would be fun to know which port the app and server are communicating over.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every application that connects to a server (via TCP) has it's IP address stored in the server in the response after you `accept` the `connect`ion.  Look there for the remote address and port.

For example:

```
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
    Socket fromClientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
```

Look at the `fromClientSocket` for your information.

Note that the client stores the information in the same place, so `getRemoteSocketAddress()` will provide the information you seek also.

```
Socket toServerSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber)
```

**[edit after clarification]**

That's a different request than the one I answered :)  You should be able to look at the source for `netstat` and see what happens when you ask for the PID of each of the sockets - `netstat -nap` IIRC

**[/edit]**

Comment: Wouldn't this only get the current app's connection info?  I am working to implement this right now. But won't this only work for the current app?  If I have the applicationInfo, can I get that application's connection info?  I have an app that has a service that monitors the network traffic generated by an app.  I want it to also get the Port that the monitored app is using.

Comment: Your edit is what I was thinking of doing.  But I didn't know if there was an easier, cleaner to get that information. Thanks.

Comment: I will accept this as the answer.  The only problem is that the native netstat doesn't allow parameters.  I haven't tested with busybox, but I believe that allows a parameterized netstat.  [edit--thanks]Thank you for your help.[/edit]

Comment: My advice is to look at the source for the linux netstat (or any of them that has this parameter) for clues as to how it can be done.